Is curved spacetime related to entropy and/or quantum decoherence?
In this article (https://physics.iitm.ac.in/~dawood/resources/pedagogical-articles/GRFessay_Kothawala_2013.pdf) in the abstract, it is said that

Spacetime curvature will generically perturb the energy eigenvalues of a system – a fact which can lead to interesting effects particularly in thermal properties of the system.

Does this mean that spacetime curvature can increase or induce entropy?
Also, in another paper (https://inspirehep.net/literature/2634121) by the same author, it says

There has been considerable interest over the past years in investigating the role of gravity in quantum phenomenon such as entanglement and decoherence. In particular, gravitational time dilation is believed to decohere superpositions of center of mass of composite quantum systems.

However, as I've been reading, these arguments form part of the quantum interpretation that the collapse of the wavefunction is caused by gravity. But these are speculative, there is nothing proven
But in this paper by Sean Carroll (https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.0298) basically he argues that in a universe devoid of matter and radiation quantum fluctuations would become "frozen" and nothing in the universe could happen
However if there was matter inside the Hubble sphere this would cause decoherence and re-instate dynamical quantum fluctuations. I thought this was obviously because of the spacetime curvature exerted by matter. If not, then why would the presence of matter cause that?
In summary, can spacetime curvature induce quantum decoherence? Can anything that has mass (and therefore curves spacetime) induce decoherence?

There is no such thing as a collapse of the wave function. I have no idea how gravity is supposed to be able to do something that does not exist in the first place.

When information is copied out of a quantum system interference is suppressed: this is called decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
Electromagnetic interactions are relatively strong and cause systems to decohere very quickly on a macroscopic scale, e.g. a dust grain at room temperature will decohere in something like $10^{-18}s$ (Section 4.1.2 of the above reference). Gravitational interactions are weaker and will decohere objects more slowly:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2402.11663
Collapse is incompatible with quantum measurement theory as it is actually used in calculations:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.05973
Collapse theories also can't currently reproduce predictions of relativistic quantum theories, i.e. - the vast bulk of all experimental predictions of quantum theory including every experiment involving light:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568
It is also unclear what benefit a collapse theory could provide since quantum theory without collapse modifications explains the result of experiments.

so gravity could cause decoherence but causing the wavefunction to collapse is difficult and speculative? @alanf

I don't know what you mean by difficult in this context. the unmodified equations of motion of qm don't include collapse and proposed modifications have unsolved problems and no clear benefits.

I meant to ask if you were saying that while on the one hand it's proven that gravity could decohere systems more slowly than EM radiation through gravitational interactions, on the other hand gravity causing the collapse of the wavefunction is a speculative topic and not very well supported/defined? @alanf

Gravity causing decoherence hasn't been tested experimentally. There is no theory of wavefunction collapse from gravity or any other mechanism that currently reproduces any of the predictions of relativistic quantum theories, including very well tested implications. As such I regard wavefunction collapse as speculative and also not well motivated.

If you want to read about collapse theories see https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.14969v1 but I regard them as a dead end.

sorry when you said "Electromagnetic interactions are relatively strong and cause systems to decohere very quickly on a macroscopic scale, e.g. a dust grain at room temperature will decohere in something like 10−18s
(Section 4.1.2 of the above reference). Gravitational interactions are weaker and will decohere objects more slowly" I thought that this implied that it was measured that gravity can decohere (although more slowly than EM interactions). But even if it has not been proven, is decoherence by gravity well motivated (contrary to it causing the collapse of the wavefunction)? @alanf

Gravitational interactions are weaker. So it will copy information out of systems more slowly and will cause decoherence more slowly as explained in the linked paper. This is motivated by relatively straightforward application of existing physics compatible with the principles of quantum theory and relativity, unlike collapse.
